# Creating a grammar for a a language for instructions, with repititions

Tags: formal-grammars, parsers, left-recursion

I have a language that consists of instructions for movement on a 2D-plane. You start at coordinate **[0,0]**

The instructions

```
DOWN 1 UP 10 LEFT 5 RIGHT 1
```

means you will move to coordinate **[9,-4]**.

There is also the REP command which means you perform the instructions inside the REP X times.

For example

```
REP 2 "DOWN 1 FORWARD 10 LEFT 5 RIGHT 1"
```

means you will move to coordinate **[18,-8]**.

I came up with this grammar

```
Instruction --> DOWN Num | UP Num | LEFT Num | Right Num | REP Num " Sequence "

Sequence --> Instruction Sequence | Instruction
```

Which works to some extent. However I want to be able to parse the grammar using recursive descent and if I am not not mistaken you can't do that with grammars that use left recursion.

Any ideas on how I could alter my grammar to make it suitable for recursive descent?

Comment: But there is no left recursion there, is there?

Comment: @harold isn't Sequence --> Instruction Sequence | Instruction left recursion?

Comment: But `Instruction` cannot be empty, so there is always some terminal before the recursion into an other `Sequence`.

Comment: **Left** recursion is, by definition, where the recursive non-terminal appears as the **left**most symbol in a replacement. `Sequence -> Instruction Sequence` is **right** recursion.

Comment: A bigger problem for parsing will be the difficulty of knowing whether a `"` starts or ends a repetition, assuming that repetitions can be nested. (And if they can't be nested, then your grammar is incorrect.)

Comment: @rici ah thanks I understand left recursion now :)

Comment: @rici I would like to be able to do nested repititions aswell. Do you have any idea on how I could approach that?

Comment: @user105075: maybe use parentheses, braces or brackets instead of quotes? That is, a pair of symbols with definite open and close semantics.